# If path does not exist, skip FOREACH

Tags: powershell

I have a question that I hope one of you can help me with.
The following script does its job, it sends the email of the folders that are older than 30 days.
I want to add 2 more features...

- If the OwnerEmail.txt is not there or empty.. it will not send the email.
- If there are not folders older than 30 days, it will not send the email.

I am just having problems using the CONTINUE feature to skip the ForEach

```
$ParentFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Test\WRA" -Directory | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($SubFolder in $ParentFolders) {
    $Contact = Get-Content -Path ($SubFolder + "\OwnerEmail.txt")
    $emailTime = (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
    $WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | 
    Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, CreationTime |

    ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "
        <h2>Current Nuix Case(s)</h2> 
        <body>
            Report was sent on $emailTime
            <br></br>
            When you have a moment can you please confirm if any of these cases can be removed from Nuix:
        <body> 
        <br></br> " | 
    
    $WRAHTMLReport = $WRAHTMLReport -join ""
    Start-Sleep -s 2

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mail.company.com -to $Contact -from cubam1@company.com -Subject "Nuix Cases" -Body $WRAHTMLReport -BodyAsHtml

}
```

Comment: your `Where-Object` filter can have multiple tests ... so just add them there. [*grin*]

Comment: PreContent is placed between the opening `<body>` and `<table>` tags so you should not include your own `<body></body>` tags

Comment: Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it could look something like this, note that I'm only showing the relevant parts of the code.

I think in this case, is safe to put the `$emailTime` outside the loop since you're only gathering the date in `MM/dd/yyyy` format and, I also added the `$folderLimitDate` outside the loop.

This variable contains the HTML body
`$mailBody = ConvertTo-Html -InputObject $WRAHTMLReport...` so remember to change the `-Body $mailBody` on `Send-MailMessage`

```
$emailTime = (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
$folderLimitDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

foreach ($SubFolder in $ParentFolders)
{
    
    $path = Join-Path $SubFolder -ChildPath 'OwnerEmail.txt'
    
    # If OwnerEmail.txt doesn't exist on this path,
    # go to next loop iteration
    if(-not(Test-Path $path)){ continue }
    
    $Contact = Get-Content $path

    $WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory |
    Where-Object LastWriteTime -LT $folderLimitDate |
    Select-Object Name, CreationTime

    # If this variable is null, go to next loop iteration
    if(-not $WRAHTMLReport){ continue }

    [string]$mailBody = ConvertTo-Html -InputObject $WRAHTMLReport...
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: You are always saving me Santiago!!, Thank you so much!, it worked

Comment: @Miguel hehe, no problem! happy to help! :)